# IntelliJ IDEA a single run-debug configuration

Tags: class, debugging, intellij-idea, run-configuration

Is there a way to create a single run/debug configuration so that when you create a new class, it recognizes it automatically without always having to create a new configuration for every single class that I want to run or debug? Something like TextPad, if this sounds more clear.

Comment: Here is the answer: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/temporary-and-permanent-run-debug-configurations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask Idea to execute your class: Ctrl+Shift+F10.
Idea will then create a temporary run config for your class and will execute it.